# iOS face detection CIDetectorAccuracyHigh vs CIDetectorAccuracyLow

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-detection, ciimage

I'm concerned with the time it takes to detect faces using `CIDetector`.

Using `CIDetector` with a large image such as `[rep fullScreenImage]` with `CIDetectorAccuracyHigh` should produce best results and longest execution time. The execution time consists of decoding the image and then running the detection on the bitmap image. This is more noticeable on older devices.

To save execution time, should I use:

1. `[rep aspectRatioThumbnail]` & `CIDetectorAccuracyHigh`
2. `[rep fullScreenImage]` & `CIDetectorAccuracyLow`
3. Other ideas?

Comment: Any answer to this question is likely to be opinion-based. You should profile both of the above and see how they perform for your particular case and use whichever one you deem appropriate from your tests.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually on it. I'm looking for an answer that is more from a best-practice perspective. There is very little documentation on how CIDetectorAccuracyXXX affects the algorithm.